# Symbolic link for uploads in wordpress

Tags: uploads

Hi i am a new bie in wordpress.

i use load balancer for my sites. So the request can be processed by any of the 4 servers.
so i moved all contents from **/wp-content/uploads** to the centralised server **/images/myblog/wp-content/uploads** and created a symbolic link to it.

Now the problem is, access to media contents results in 404 error. Can you please explain, is anything i am missing out.

Comment: Does your webserver have symlinks turned off?  (For instance, in Apache, the FollowSymLinks or FollowSymlinksIfOwnerMatch options.)  Also, are the file & directory permissions correct?

Comment: @Pat : How can i verify that? Can you help me out

Comment: I have limited experience using symlinks in WordPress.  My comment was meant to eliminate obvious possible issues. If you're not running your own server, you'll need to ask your hosting provider about the `FollowSymlinks` option (or equivalent, if it's not Apache).  You might be able to add it to your `.htaccess` file, too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that your web server has symlinks enabled. For Apache2, this is `Options FollowSymLinks`. For Nginx, the option is `disable_symlinks off;`. If you are not using either of these, you may need to consult your servers documentation.

If you are you using a web hosting provide, you can also see if there is an option in their dashboard. If not, you may need to contact their support team to see if they can help you.

Also, make sure that your filesystem permissions are correct. You may get a permission denied error if they are wrong.